# Loading text file in oracle from unix system

Tags: oracle, unix, sql-loader

I am having text file contaning field in below manner.

```
"64252368","7489040","305762",
"64285217","12132108","787341",
```

I am using a below control file.

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE test_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '",'

(
        LEARNEVENT_ID,
        ORGANIZATION,
        COURSE_ID
)
```

But, I am getting the error:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table test_table, column LEARNEVENT_ID
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Kindly help me on it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your ctl file to include `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` option.

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE test_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
(
        LEARNEVENT_ID,
        ORGANIZATION,
        COURSE_ID
)
```

I'd recommend [reading](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ) up on [SQL*Loader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm).

Comment: Thanks Ben, when i am trying to use enclosed by in my control file now geeting below error.  no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field

Comment: If you data ends in a comma, then using `TRAILING NULLCOLS`. Remove this line if it doesn't...

Comment: my data end with comma. kindly suggest me what should i have to do in this case?

Comment: Apparently `TRAILING NULLCOLS` isn't needed in this situation. It worked for me without.., which I find a little confusing but never mind.

Comment: @Praveenk.Agrawal : If you are content with this answer you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), which is how all the sites on StackExchange (including this one) work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lays with the encapsulation of the numbers with the quotes " " and your fields terminated by '",' simply does not strip the quotes.

Try this

```
OPTIONS(SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE test_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  LEARNEVENT_ID "replace ( :LEARNEVENT_ID ,'"', '')",
  ORGINAZATION "replace ( :ORGINAZATION ,'"', '')",
  COURSE_ID "replace ( :COURSE_ID ,'"', '')"
)
```

Comment: okay those are only numbers, but instead you should used Ben's solution.

Comment: The question only applies to numbers.